# How to override built in ipv6 module with customized ipv6 module in Linux Kernl

Tags: linux-kernel, ipv6, insmod

I have been using ubuntu version 13.04 which has built in ipv6 module,I have customized the ipv6 module source, I have also generated the customized ipv6.ko.

I tried blacklisting the ipv6 module and do a 'insmod ipv6.ko' but it doesnt work..!!  It fails with

Invalid ModuLE Format
$:/usr/src/linux-source-3.8.0/net/ipv6# insmod ipv6.ko
Error: could not insert module ipv6.ko: Invalid module format

cd /var/log
less syslog >> kernel: [  826.450597] ipv6: exports duplicate symbol icmpv6_err_convert (owned by kernel)

Since the ipv6 module is built in,how can I override it with my customized module? Is there any alternative method??It will be a great if some one can help me with a soultion

Thanks
Shiney

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Build a kernel without the `ipv6` module built-in.